# I cant get my search query to execute correctly, it keeps pulling up duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new at this and stuck here. I think this is just a problem with how I'm writing my queries. I have two tables `project` and `project_participant`. I'm trying to get all the records from `project` (parent table), joined to a specific, associated row from `project_participant` (child table) and display them all. So every record contained in `project` would be displayed once, and only once, because each "project" will only have one single row each that it relates to in the  `project_participant` table that has a field categorizing it as "Sponsor".

When I run the query in phpmyadmin just like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM project
  NATURAL JOIN project_participant
WHERE project.project_id = project_participant.project_id
  AND project_participant.participant_category = "Sponsor";
```

It works the way I want it to. But in my get_project.php file, when I try to combine this query with a search function, It will pull up duplicate rows for each record in `project`. It will have a different row for each existing participant related to the project even though the other related participants are not categorized as "Sponsor" (They can be Sponsor, Staff, Faculty, etc.)

More information: When I first navigate to the get_project.php page, the records are displayed correctly. but when I enter text into the search bar and try to search it, the search doesn't work or filter anything, it just pulls up the duplicates as mentioned above. I know this is close to working, because it worked correctly when I only searching the `project` table before, I tried to add the join to the `project_participant` into the query. I just can't seem to figure this one out. Here is the code for my get_project.php file:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
//include the pmo_functions.php file to add header, footer, and navbar
include 'pmo_functions.php';
include 'navbar.php';
//make a connection to the database for these specific tasks
$conn = pdo_connect_mysql();
/* Get the page via GET request (URL param: page), if not enough records exist for there to
be more than one page, default the page to 1*/
$page = isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
// Number of records to show on each page, default to 5
$records_per_page = isset($_GET['records_per_page']) && (is_numeric($_GET['records_per_page']) || $_GET['records_per_page'] == 'All') ? $_GET['records_per_page'] : 5;
// These are the columns the users can "order by"
$order_by_list = array('project_id', 'project_category', 'organization_name', 'project_title', 'ksu_department', 'priority_level',
'start_date', 'end_date', 'funded', 'total_cost', 'description', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'participant_org', 'email', 'phone', 'approval');
// Get the column the user picks to order by (default to project_id)
$order_by = isset($_GET['order_by']) && in_array($_GET['order_by'], $order_by_list) ? $_GET['order_by'] : 'project_id';
// Sort by ascending or descending if specified, default to ascending
$order_sort = isset($_GET['order_sort']) && $_GET['order_sort'] == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
/*When user does a search for specific data, it will retrieve all the records in the database table
that contain the user-specified value, but it will default to only displaying 5 at a time. If the user
then selects "ALL", it will then display all of the records in the database table that contain the value the user
previously specified (on one page)*/
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    if ($records_per_page == 'All') {
        // SQL statement to get all records containing the specific search query
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM project
                               NATURAL JOIN project_participant WHERE project.project_id = project_participant.project_id AND project_participant.participant_category ="Sponsor" LIKE :search_query
                                  OR project.project_category LIKE :search_query
                                  OR project.organization_name LIKE :search_query
                                  OR project.project_title LIKE :search_query
                                  OR project.ksu_department LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project.priority_level LIKE :search_query
                                  OR project.start_date LIKE :search_query
                                  OR project.end_date LIKE :search_query
                                  OR project.funded LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project.total_cost LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project.description LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project_participant.last_name LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project_participant.first_name LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project_participant.participant_org LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project_participant.email LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project_participant.phone LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project.approval LIKE :search_query
                                ORDER BY ' . $order_by . ' ' . $order_sort);
        $stmt->bindValue(':search_query', '%' . $_GET['search'] . '%');
    } else {
        /*After the user does a search for records containing specific data, they can navigate back and
        forth between pages of the records that contain the specific data, and also limit the amout of
        these records they want displayed at a time for each page*/
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM project
                                NATURAL JOIN project_participant WHERE project.project_id = project_participant.project_id AND project_participant.participant_category = "Sponsor" LIKE :search_query
                                OR project.project_category LIKE :search_query
                                OR project.organization_name LIKE :search_query
                                OR project.project_title LIKE :search_query
                                OR project.ksu_department LIKE :search_query
                                OR project.priority_level LIKE :search_query
                                OR project.start_date LIKE :search_query
                                OR project.end_date LIKE :search_query
                                OR project.funded LIKE :search_query
                                OR project.total_cost LIKE :search_query
                                OR project.description LIKE :search_query
                                OR project_participant.last_name LIKE :search_query
                                OR project_participant.first_name LIKE :search_query
                                OR project_participant.participant_org LIKE :search_query
                                OR project_participant.email LIKE :search_query
                                OR project_participant.phone LIKE :search_query
                                OR project.approval LIKE :search_query
                                ORDER BY ' . $order_by . ' ' . $order_sort . '
                                LIMIT :current_page, :record_per_page');
        $stmt->bindValue(':search_query', '%' . $_GET['search'] . '%');
        $stmt->bindValue(':current_page', ($page-1)*(int)$records_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':record_per_page', (int)$records_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
}
/*If the user did not specify any data to search for and just clicked "All", it will pull up every
 single record contained in the database table on one page*/
else {
    if ($records_per_page == 'All') {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM project NATURAL JOIN project_participant WHERE project.project_id = project_participant.project_id AND project_participant.participant_category ="Sponsor" ORDER BY ' . $order_by . ' ' . $order_sort);
    }
    /*If the user did not specify any data to search for, they could navigate back and forth through pages
    that contain every single record in the database table. The user can limit the number of records they
    want to have displayed at a time (it will default to 5 at first).*/
    else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM project NATURAL JOIN project_participant WHERE project.project_id = project_participant.project_id AND project_participant.participant_category ="Sponsor" ORDER BY ' . $order_by . ' ' . $order_sort . ' LIMIT :current_page, :record_per_page');
        $stmt->bindValue(':current_page', ($page-1)*(int)$records_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':record_per_page', (int)$records_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
}
$stmt->execute();
// Fetch the records to be displayed.
$project = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
/* Get the total number of records searched that match the specified search criteria, this is so
we can see if needs to have a next and previous button*/
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project
                            NATURAL JOIN project_participant WHERE project.project_id = project_participant.project_id AND project_participant.participant_category ="Sponsor" LIKE :search_query
                            OR project.project_category LIKE :search_query
                            OR project.organization_name LIKE :search_query
                            OR project.project_title LIKE :search_query
                            OR project.ksu_department LIKE :search_query
                            OR project.priority_level LIKE :search_query
                            OR project.start_date LIKE :search_query
                            OR project.end_date LIKE :search_query
                            OR project.funded LIKE :search_query
                            OR project.total_cost LIKE :search_query
                            OR project.description LIKE :search_query
                            OR project_participant.last_name LIKE :search_query
                            OR project_participant.first_name LIKE :search_query
                            OR project_participant.participant_org LIKE :search_query
                            OR project_participant.email LIKE :search_query
                            OR project_participant.phone LIKE :search_query
                            OR project.approval LIKE :search_query');
    $stmt->bindValue(':search_query', '%' . $_GET['search'] . '%');
    $stmt->execute();
    $num_project = $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
/*If no serch criteria was specified, just count all of the records in the database table
to see if there should be a next and previous button*/
else {
    $num_project = $conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project NATURAL JOIN project_participant WHERE project.project_id = project_participant.project_id AND project_participant.participant_category ="Sponsor"')->fetchColumn();
}
?>
<!--Add in header from pmo_functions.php and insert the title of this page, "Get Project"-->
<?=template_header('Get Project')?>
<!--beginning of container for the get project section-->
<div class="container">
    <h2>All Projects - General Project & Sponsor Information</h2>
    <!--beginning of container for a button that links back to create_project.php,
  (this "Create Project" button can be deleted and the navbar could be used instead,
    since that function is available, just thought this could be an option)
    and the custom search bar.-->
    <div>
        <div class="d-inline-block">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" href="create_project.php" role="button">Create Project</a>
        </div>
        <div class="d-inline-block">
            <form action="get_project.php" method="get">
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." value="<?=isset($_GET['search']) ? htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end of container for the Create_project.php button link and custom search bar-->
    <!--Beginning of table for records to be displayed-->
    <table>
            <!--beginning of table column header row-->
                <!--The records are ordered by project_id by default, but if the user clicks the
                column heading i.e. "Title", the records will then be ordered by "Title".-->
        <thead>

            <tr>
                            <!--Project ID column header-->
                            <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=project_id&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                                ID
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'project_id'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
                    </td>
                            <!--Project Category column header-->
                            <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=project_category&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                                Category
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'project_category'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
                    </td>
                            <!--Organization Name column header-->
                            <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=organization_name&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                                Organization
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'organization_name'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
                    </td>
                            <!--Project Title column header-->
              <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=project_title&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                                Title
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'project_title'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <!--Department column header-->
              <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=ksu_department&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                            KSU Department
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'ksu_department'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <!--Priority Level column header-->
              <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=priority_level&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                                Priority
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'priority_level'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
              </td>
                            <!--Start Date column header-->
              <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=start_date&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                            Start Date
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'start_date'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
              </td>
                            <!--End Date column header-->
              <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=end_date&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                                End Date
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'end_date'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
              </td>
                            <!--Funded column header-->
              <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=funded&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                                Funded
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'funded'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
              </td>
                            <!--Cost column header-->
                            <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=total_cost&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                                Cost
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'total_cost'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <!--Description column header-->
                            <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=description&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                            Description
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'description'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
                            </td>





                            <!--Last Name column header-->
                            <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=last_name&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                            Sponsor's Last Name
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'last_name'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <!--First Name column header-->
                            <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=first_name&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                            Sponsor's First Name
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'first_name'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <!--Participant's Organization column header-->
                            <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=participant_org&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                            Sponsor's Organizaion
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'participant_org'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <!--Email column header-->
                            <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=email&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                            Sponsor's Email
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'email'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <!--Phone column header-->
                            <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=phone&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                            Sponsor's Phone
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'phone'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
                            </td>






                            <!--Approval column header-->
                            <td>
                                <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=approval&order_sort=<?=$order_sort == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                            Approval Status
                                <?php if ($order_by == 'approval'): ?>
                                <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-<?=str_replace(array('ASC', 'DESC'), array('up', 'down'), $order_sort)?>"></i>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <!--Empty cell column header for the column containing the edit/delete icon links-->
              <td></td>
            </tr>
        </thead><!--end of table column header section-->
                <!--Body of table that will populate rows with the values of each field in a record-->
                <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($project as $project): ?>
            <tr>
                              <td><?=$project['project_id']?></td>
                                <td><?=$project['project_category']?></td>
                                <td><?=$project['organization_name']?></td>
                <td><?=$project['project_title']?></td>
                <td><?=$project['ksu_department']?></td>
                                <td><?=$project['priority_level']?></td>
                <td><?=$project['start_date']?></td>
                <td><?=$project['end_date']?></td>
                <td><?=$project['funded']?></td>
                                <td><?=$project['total_cost']?></td>
                <td><?=$project['description']?></td>
                                <td><?=$project['last_name']?></td>
                                <td><?=$project['first_name']?></td>
                                <td><?=$project['participant_org']?></td>
                                <td><?=$project['email']?></td>
                                <td><?=$project['phone']?></td>
                                <td><?=$project['approval']?></td>
                                <!--Populate the end of each row with icons links that edit and delete each record-->
                <td>
                    <a href="update_project.php?project_id=<?=$project['project_id']?>"><i class="fas fa-pen fa-xs"></i></a>
                    <a href="delete_project.php?project_id=<?=$project['project_id']?>"><i class="fas fa-trash fa-xs"></i></a>
                                        <a href="view_project.php?project_id=<?=$project['project_id']?>"><i class="fas fa-eye fa-xs"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        <!--End of table for records to be displayed-->
  <!--Beginning of container for the bottom of the get project section-->
    <div>
        <!--Beginning of container for the records per page selections-->
        <div>
            <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=5&order_by=<?=$order_by?>&order_sort=<?=$order_sort?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">5</a>
            <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=10&order_by=<?=$order_by?>&order_sort=<?=$order_sort?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">10</a>
            <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=20&order_by=<?=$order_by?>&order_sort=<?=$order_sort?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">20</a>
            <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=50&order_by=<?=$order_by?>&order_sort=<?=$order_sort?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">50</a>
            <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=100&order_by=<?=$order_by?>&order_sort=<?=$order_sort?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">100</a>
            <a href="get_project.php?page=1&records_per_page=All&order_by=<?=$order_by?>&order_sort=<?=$order_sort?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">All</a>
        </div>
        <!--End of container for the records per page selections-->
        <!--Beginning of container for the pagination
        (displays Page and the page number, and a page navigation arrow the user can
      click to move page to page).-->
        <div>
            <?php if ($page > 1): ?>
            <a href="get_project.php?page=<?=$page-1?>&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=<?=$order_by?>&order_sort=<?=$order_sort?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
                <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left fa-sm"></i>
            </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!--Beginning of container for "Page" and the page number displayed-->
            <div href="get_project.php?page=<?=$page?>&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=<?=$order_by?>&order_sort=<?=$order_sort?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
            Page <?=$page?>
            </div>
            <!--End of container for just the page and number displayed-->
            <?php if ($records_per_page != 'All' && $page*$records_per_page < $num_project): ?>
            <a href="get_project.php?page=<?=$page+1?>&records_per_page=<?=$records_per_page?>&order_by=<?=$order_by?>&order_sort=<?=$order_sort?><?=isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . htmlentities($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''?>">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right fa-sm"></i>
            </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <!--End of container for the pagination-->
    </div>
    <!--End of container for the bottom of the get project section-->
</div>
<!--end of container for the get project section-->
<!--Add in footer from pmo_functions.php-->
<?=template_footer()?>
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Tip of today: Skip the NATURAL JOIN's, specify the join conditions. (Now you do both...)

Answer (score 0):

You can select it as distinct and join it to the project. Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM project
                               iNNER JOIN project_participant ON (project.project_id = project_participant.project_id) AND project_participant.participant_category ="Sponsor" LIKE :search_query
                                  OR project.project_category LIKE :search_query
                                  OR project.organization_name LIKE :search_query
                                  OR project.project_title LIKE :search_query
                                  OR project.ksu_department LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project.priority_level LIKE :search_query
                                  OR project.start_date LIKE :search_query
                                  OR project.end_date LIKE :search_query
                                  OR project.funded LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project.total_cost LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project.description LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project_participant.last_name LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project_participant.first_name LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project_participant.participant_org LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project_participant.email LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project_participant.phone LIKE :search_query
                                    OR project.approval LIKE :search_query
                                ORDER BY
```

Apologies to the moderators, i'm not use to answering questions on stackoverflow but trying to familiarize myself with it. so please correct where neccessary.